# What is the most effective tool to monitor customer usage of managed packages?

Tags: apex, managed-package, isv, partner, usagemetrics

We are an ISV partner and have managed packages that our customers are using actively. We want to know some statistics on usage of our pages/components. We have installed the [usage metrics app provided by SF](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5FMvEAN); however, it is very limited in functionality and usage. I was wondering if there is a better tool we can use for this purpose instead of building our own, which obviously would be more time-consuming.